# i need helping having it print the random names

Tags: python

im trying to make it so the code prints out the random roles and the random name but when i run the code it gives <**main**.players object at 0x7f7b87db0bb0> get the <**main**.items object at 0x7f7b87dbf3d0> this response

i tried to add .name to the print but it would say that they have no attributes
i want it to print out the random item and roles name

```
import random
class players:
  def __init__ (self, role, inkey):
    self.name = role
    self.key=inkey
class items:
  def __init__ (self, name):
    self.itemname = name
    self.owner=""


Roles=[["Hacker","Q"],["Lookout","P"],["Money Man","Z"],["Explosive expert","M"]]

objectroles=[]

for i in Roles:
  object1 = players(i[0],i[1])
  objectroles.append(object1)

Items=["Goggles","Headset","Torch","Explosives","Map","Laptop","Gloves","Drill"]

objectitems = []

for i in Items:
  object2 = items(i)
  objectitems.append(object2)

templist=[]

def get():
  global templist
  item1=random.choice(objectitems)
  role1=random.choice(objectroles)
  print(role1,"get the", item1)
  templist.append(item1)
get()

def take():
  global templist
  item1=random.choice(objectitems)
  role1=random.choice(objectroles)
  print(role1,"take the", item1)
  templist.append(item1)
take()
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `__str__` methods to your classes to change the way that they're printed:

```
class players:
  def __init__ (self, role, inkey):
    self.name = role
    self.key=inkey
  def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class items:
  def __init__ (self, name):
    self.itemname = name
    self.owner=""
  def __str__(self):
    return self.itemname
```